# How to add friends from pc to ps4?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I've been trying for a while to add a friend who plays on ps4 and i'm on my pc, the friending system just says: "user not found". I'd appreciate any help with this, thanks in advance!
 <sub>Note: I have used epic name, and we have tried it where the person i'm trying to add tries to add me.</sub>

Comment: Did he link his PSN account to an Epic account? You just said: "epic name."

Answer (score 1):

Your probably using his PSN name. You need to use his EPIC GAMES name for it work. Same thing happened to me when I tried friending a fortnite PS4 user.

Comment: i did use the epic name, sorry i prbably should've mentioned this...